# No updates since mid-December?

Tags: updates, history

I usually get screen messages at least once a week for available security updates (or other updates) and I apply them immediately. But I haven't seen one since mid-December, which seems odd. Is anyone else noticing this? Based on comments in a similar post, I checked history.log.1 and found that the last event was 12/18/22. I'm running 22.04.1 LTS.

Comment: I guess the Ubuntu developers also take the time off during Christmas...

Comment: I got updates. You need to check settings and the mirrors in use.

Comment: The last Ubuntu security update of 2022 was announced on December 16.

Comment: The lists of updates (for each release) get published in a number of places; in the Ubuntu Weekly Newsletter for example (*which had no updates this week for example, but that's common during the Christmas-NewYear cycle*) as its normal for updates to occur almost every other week but that one, HOWEVER they don't hit every box (*it'll depend on what packages you have installed!*).  Did you look up one of the many lists of updates available to see if you should expect to see any?

Comment: Try copying and pasting into the terminal:
`sudo add-apt-repository universe ** sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`

Comment: I have received linux-firmware update today.

Answer (score 2):

My prior comment refers to various places where security updates are provided..  I used as example the Ubuntu Weekly Newsletter, where [issue 767 (*for the week of 18-24 December*) has listed](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter/Issue767#Ubuntu_22.04_Updates)

> **Ubuntu 22.04 Updates**
>
> - linux-restricted-modules-hwe-5.19
>   5.19.0-28.29~22.04.1 - https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/jammy-changes/2022-December/017878.html
> - linux-meta-hwe-5.19 5.19.0.28.29~22.04.6 -
>   https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/jammy-changes/2022-December/017879.html
> - linux-hwe-5.19 5.19.0-28.29~22.04.1 -
>   https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/jammy-changes/2022-December/017880.html
> - linux-signed-hwe-5.19 5.19.0-28.29~22.04.1 -
>   https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/jammy-changes/2022-December/017881.html
> - linux-restricted-signatures-hwe-5.19 5.19.0-28.29~22.04.1 -
>   https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/jammy-changes/2022-December/017882.html
> - linux-restricted-modules-nvidia-5.19 5.19.0-1002.2 -
>   https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/jammy-changes/2022-December/017883.html
> - linux-nvidia-5.19 5.19.0-1002.2 -
>   https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/jammy-changes/2022-December/017884.html
> - linux-meta-nvidia-5.19 5.19.0.1002.2 -
>   https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/jammy-changes/2022-December/017886.html
> - linux-signed-nvidia-5.19 5.19.0-1002.2 -
>   https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/jammy-changes/2022-December/017885.html
> - linux-restricted-signatures-nvidia-5.19 5.19.0-1002.2 -
>   https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/jammy-changes/2022-December/017887.html
>
> End of Standard Support: April 2027

Not all *jammy* (22.04) systems will have all those package installed, thus may not receive those patches, so you're best reading the lists yourself if you're worried.

I used that issue of the UWN as example; that is not the *latest* issue, but as stated the [current] [latest issue (UWN 768) has no updates reported](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter/Issue768#Ubuntu_22.04_Updates).

If you're worried about security updates, and whether or not you've missed any, I suggest subscribing to one of the many places where they're available (RSS feed, ML posted to you etc).  It was only earlier today that I posted the latest issue of UWN to subscribers (*I'm using UWN as example only because I'm very aware of it, being a contributor, but there are multiple ways to get such lists!*).

Comment: this is only a *longer* form of the comment I left earlier...   roughly the same time as subscribers to ubuntu-news@lists.ubuntu.com would have received their *latest* UWN copy too...

Comment: I didn't vote to close, but I still feel that a minimum effort of research combined with common sense would render this question obsolete (which is probably well-reflected in the question score).. 

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 software updates resumed today with a kernel update after a one months lapse with no updates.